# Where does my Log4J output go to(ran the HelloWorld Log4J example)?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm trying to learn Log4J and have a problem with understanding how to incorporate the logging and view output. This is my code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorldLog4J {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Hello, World! ammmm");
    }



}
```

Where does the output go to ? I assume that there's some text file in the log4j install-directory?

This is how my log4J directories looks like

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post your log4j.properties file. In many cases , this is how specify the output file in log4j.properties file :-

```
 log4j.appender.outLogger.File=appname-out.log # normal output

 log4j.appender.errLogger.File=appname-err.log # Error due to logger.error
```